# Cisco 1921, SMTP, and NAT on multiple Exchange Servers

Tags: cisco, router, nat, high-availability, exchange-2013

In a LAN environment, I have 3 exchange servers that have been deployed for high availability and failover in case one of the 3 servers becomes unavailable.

Currently, my NAT settings only send packets to the first server. I would like the ability to have emails (packets) sent on the network to servers 2 and 3 as well in the case that any of the three become unavailable.

How should I do this on my Cisco router?

Currently, I have NAT setting

ip nat inside source static tcp 10.200.15.33 25 96.92.221.221 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.200.15.33 110 96.92.221.221 25 extendable
etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inside destination` NAT instead of `inside source` NAT to set up a pool of inside addresses, which can be used in a rotary fashion:

> **Destination Address Rotary Translation**
>
> A dynamic form of destination translation can be configured for some
>   outside-to-inside traffic. Once a mapping is set up, a destination
>   address matching one of those on an access list will be replaced with
>   an address from a rotary pool. Allocation is done in a round-robin
>   basis, performed only when a new connection is opened from the outside
>   to the inside. All non-TCP traffic is passed untranslated (unless
>   other translations are in effect). This feature was designed to
>   provide protocol translation load distribution. It is not designed nor
>   intended to be used as a substitute technology for Cisco's
>   LocalDirector product. Destination address rotary translation should
>   not be used to provide web service load balancing because, like
>   vanilla DNS, it knows nothing about service availability. As a result,
>   if a web server were to become offline, the destination address rotary
>   translation feature would continue to send requests to the downed
>   server.
>
> ```
> ip nat inside destination { list <acl> pool <name> | static <global-ip> <local-ip> }
> ```
>
> This command is similar to the source translation command. For dynamic
>   destination translation to make any sense, the pool should be a
>   rotary-type pool.

Comment: Would this kind of setup be favorable and appropriate for Exchange? My concern is how each of the exchange servers would handle a situation where an identical piece of email was received on each of the three servers (due to the network setup).

Comment: The traffic isn't sent to all three servers. A single flow will be sent to only one server, but each server will get a new flow in turn. I really can't comment on how suitable it is for an Exchange server. Your only other option is to put in a load balancer behind the router, and NAT to it. A dedicated load balancer is suitable for all types of traffic, but it probably costs more than your router did.